# HTML Overview, Help me

Tags: html, tags, categories

When i try to fully understand something i try to visualize in order to grasp it, by categorizing, listing etc etc.

Now, i wanna understand HTML, it seems that it goes something like this:
Its all made of tags.
HTML tags can be divided by their purpose:

1) Tags for Browser Format like "article", "section", "cite",etc, they dont add anything visual or at direct usefulness to the user, they are there to help better manage webpages.

2) Tags for Visual Format like "italics", "bold", "break line", etc they are used to only provide a visual layout.

3) Interactive Tags like links, pictures, music, video.

4) Functional Tags like input forms, "menu", "select" etc, they have interactive and functional uses.

Is this right? am i missing something or confused anything?
Is there a better way to categorize em?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do these categories help http://www.html-5.com/tags/index.html. I think there are a few more than 4 (taking into account declarations, scripts etc.)

Comment: You are overkilling yourself. Dont bother much in categorising jump start to build your app things will automatically fall in your way else `google` ;)

Comment: @dtryon i gave a quick look and i think it can be very helpful, i'll look into it right now, thnx.

Comment: Read [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/spec.html#semantics). It provides categorization of the elements right there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right on the money with those categories. HTML is more confusing now, with HTML5, than it used to be. In older versions, all tags "did" something. Mostly, they represented a predefined way of formatting things. With CSS3, all these predefined standards can be changed, and any tag can do anything. That's why some tags introduced in HTML5, like article, section and cite, merely try to organize information on the page, leaving the look and feel up to the designer/programmer (through CSS and Javascript). After all, there's no point on defining how  will look like if most people will use CSS to customize it anyway.

A few tags, however, do have a specific interactive behavior that can't be changed with CSS (e.g. video). But in general, I would say HTML is slowly evolving towards tags that only structure the information, as in XML, and leave all formatting to CSS, and all interaction to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It’s mostly right, with some conceptual confusion. HTML is really made of elements, which are nodes in a document tree; tags are just a way of indicating elements. Moreover,

1. Elements like `article` are just proposed HTML5 elements, assumed to be treated as indicating meaning and structure, but taken just as containers by current browser. The `cite` element more or less means italics, though the theory is that it is semantic and means citation.
2. Tags for purely visual formatting are generally regarded as no-no these days, though they have their use. The `br` tag is controversial; it is best used only when the content itself contains a line break (e.g., between lines of a postal address, or stanzas of a poem).
3. Links are interactive, but pictures, music, and video are embedded content (though they may have interactive controls).
4. Forms are a special type of interaction.

The [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) has a useful classification (sections 9 to 18).